# UITableCell Centered with Shadow

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I would like to build my UITableView in similar way to Google+ app, which has:

1. UITableCell width of about 310 I guess but the important thing is they centered, I dont know how to achieve that...
2. There is a 1-2 pixels of shadow beneath the cell.

Please help me to understand how to position my cells the same way and how to add the shadow effect.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I finally got the solution.

I used a background image for each cell that takes the whole width (I kind of cheated) and incorporate the shadow and the 10px separation in the background image.

Of course I had to use Photoshop or similar program to achieve that. so the UITableView and the Cell width should be 320, and the height of the cell should contain the shadow and the separation as well.

This is how I make the table to look exactly like I want it to be!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. UITableCell width of about 310 I guess but the important thing is they centered, I dont know how to achieve that... : You'll have to create a own subclass of `UITableViewCell`. Here you can position the controls which you need however you need. You can achieve the above shown `UITableView` only by creating your custom `UITableViewCell`. You can refer [this](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-design-a-custom-uitableviewcell-from-scratch/1292/)
2. There is a 1-2 pixels of shadow beneath the cell. : This can be possible only by using the image with shadow as a background of your customized `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there should be a simpler way to achieve (2). and about (1) - isn't there a way to center the UITableViewCell?